# .last updated files every time I fetch this

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Please check and let me know if I was making some mistake in defining things in pom

tried various dependencies for each same thing is happening I am working on an existing project so haven't changed pom much please guide me so I can add dependency and work on them

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.aol.obi.notify</groupId>
<artifactId>subscription_settlement_notify</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>lambda-subscription-settlement-notify</name>
<!-- <url>https://github.com/vinayselvaraj/lambda-jdbc-sample</url> -->

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>obi-release</id>
        <url>https://artifactory.ouroath.com/artifactory/obi-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-cache</id>
        <url>https://artifactory.ouroath.com/artifactory/yahoo-maven-cache</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>local-release</id>
        <url>https://artifactory.ouroath.com/artifactory/maven-local-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-snapshot</id>
        <url>http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.319</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--  dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>18.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I want to know if i have defined something wrong in pom .As i have tried setting up this project on two systems.But maven dependencies are not resolved always they fetch only .lastupdated files

Comment: Ah I understand, sorry. Why do you have set the repositories? Can you try to remove it?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i have tried that too

Comment: And your build has access to the internet?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes it has rare time it work for some dependencies

Comment: can you try to execute mvn clean install -U

Comment: already tried @SimonMartinelli